# How do I make the back faces of a transparent object hidden while other individual objects behind it remain visible?

Tags: transparency, faces, visibility

This is the scene in material mode
[image]

Render mode with Z transparency
[image]

The same thing but now with mask transparency
[image]

Can I make the back faces of the front cube hidden like the 3rd image, while the black cube behind it is still visible like in the 2nd image?

Answer (score 4):

i know that your'e using blender internal, but you probably should use cycles or eevee (eevee is only in blender 2.80^).

with this simple node setup you should get the result below.

[image]

Result.
[image]